# Handling Scroll bars with jQuery event Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-and-drop, z-index

I have a room div with some toy divs arranged on it, see [image]

Toys are absolutly positioned and are drag-able with in the walls of the room . The room container div has a fixed height and height, so the room has horizontal as well as vertical scrolls. I use [jquery event drag](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag) plug-in for setting up DnD. I managed to set up the toys drag only with in the lomits of the wall, but when there are scrolls, component is moving a little ouside the wall (only up to the actual width of the wall).

I want to show only a portion of the toy as shown below [image]

I tried setting the `z-index`, but has no effect, any one has better idea?

Comment: Got something, need to absolutely position bot the room div and the room container div

Answer (score 2):

Withouth seeing the actual code, i guess overflow:hidden could solve this?

Comment: `overflow:hidden` has no effect as the `toy` divs are absolutely positioned.

Comment: see my answer above, overflow:hidden *should* be the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can used scrollTo plugin http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ to work with scrollbars

Answer (score 1):

the example below shows that overflow:hidden does indeed do what you're asking. Something is up with your code, but we can't help you unless you post it!

[alt text http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/9594/example1281542227415.png](http://img155.imageshack.us/img155/9594/example1281542227415.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            #container {
                background-color:#ddddff;
                height:300px;
                overflow:hidden;
                position:relative;
                width:300px;
            }

            #container .child {
                background-color:#ddffdd;
                height:50px;
                position:absolute;
                width:50px;
            }

            #container .child1 {
                left:100px;
                top:70px;
            }

            #container .child2 {
                left:270px;
                top:170px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="container">
            <div class="child child1"></div>
            <div class="child child2"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```